# How to save file uploaded by user in Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm using a Slack Bolt Python SDK to collect files uploaded by user. When a user uploads a file to the slack bot app, the bot will recognize the event and the reveived body is sth like:

```
{'token': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'team_id': 'Ttttttttt',
 'enterprise_id': 'Eeeeee',
 'api_app_id': 'Aaaaaaaa',
 'event': {'type': 'message', 
           'text': '', 
           'files': [{'id': 'Fffffff', 
                      ......
                      'mode': 'snippet', 
                      'is_external': False, 
                      'external_type': '', 
                      'is_public': False, 
                      'public_url_shared': False, 
                      'display_as_bot': False, 'username': '', 
                      'url_private': 'https://url/file.xlsx', 
                      'url_private_download': 'https://url2/file.xlsx', 
                      'permalink': 'https://url3/file.xlsx', 
                      'permalink_public': 'https://url3', 
                      ......
```

Given the returned value, how can I obtain the file and save it? I have tried sth like

```
file_path = body['event']['files'][0]['url_private_download']
urllib.request.urlretrieve (file_path, "./temple.xlsx")
```

But the file saved is not in xlsx format but in html format. Can anyone tell me how to save the file correctly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide an authorization header while making the request to download the file:

```
Authorization: Bearer A_VALID_TOKEN
```

A_VALID_TOKEN is a OAuth token, that has `files.read` scope.

You can read more here: https://api.slack.com/types/file#auth

It looks like the html file you get is just a default response from Slack when there is no auth token provided.